# Way to include a .js inside a .js?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include javascript file inside javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

Is this possible?  Including a reference to another .js that your current .js file code is reliant on instead of having to add 2 includes in every page to ensure that both those files are there?

I assume the answer is no...as I have not found any info on it on the net so far.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Answer (score 2):

You can use document.write to create a `<script>` element.

But there's no include in js.

Answer (score 0):

coffeeaddict,

Try this article:

http://www.chapter31.com/2006/12/07/including-js-files-from-within-js-files/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about this but I know this is great for intellisense . Take Visual studios for instance they got a vs-doc for jquery. You add a reference of the vs-doc into your .js file and you got intellisense.

Otherwise I don't know if there is a point to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. It's slightly awkward but you can do it. There are several different ways in fact, but the simplest is to add a `<script>` tag with the appropriate "src" value, and put all your dependent code in an "onload" handler of that element. Your script will then run after the other one finishes loading.